# Lubuntu 14.04 Session loss upon screen locking and power management issues

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, suspend, lock-screen, session

1. When I screen lock (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>) on my Lubuntu 14.04 LTS system, my session is restarted when I log back in. This causes me to lose any programs I had running prior to the lock.
2. Power management doesn't' seem to work and I haven't found any relevant articles regarding my issue. Basically, my computer doesn't 'sleep' after 60 minutes (the time I've set in power manager)

I will be happy to provide any information needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't Ctrl-Alt-L the shortcut for locking and Ctrl-Alt-Del the shortcut for logout (usually in Ubuntu, but in Lubuntu as well)?